# Adjective after Verb in "He looks tired"

Tags: verbs, adjectives

1. How do we call the verb "looks"? Is it stative verb?
2. How do we call the adjective "tired"? Any linguistic term to call it? Is it attributive adjective?

Comment: "**What** do we call....?"

Comment: Have you done any previous research? For example, did you look up "stative verb" in any of the hundred English Language websites that populate the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "looks" is a stative verb in "He looks tired."  It means he appears tired.  The adjective describing the subject is a predicative adjective, meaning that as a complement to the subject, it appears after the verb.

An attributive adjective appears with the noun it modifies, usually before.  In the "the red ball," "red" is attributive.  In "the ball is red," "red" is predicative.

Note that "look" has dynamic uses:

> He **looks** *tiredly* at the passing scene.

Here "look" means the action of gazing, not the state of the gazer, and it requires an *adverb*.

Comment: Can we also call the adjective "tired" as object complement?

Comment: No, because there's no object in "He looks tired."  Stative verbs are intransitive, i.e., they don't convey action to an object.  "Complement" here means to complete the meaning, and "tired" refers to the subject.  In the sentence "They elected him president," "president" is an objective complement, helping to complete the description of "him," the direct object of "elected."